# How to send other POST data with TINYMCE images_upload_handler

Tags: javascript, php, image, tinymce

I've got an image handler working in TinyMCE:

```js
images_upload_handler: function (blobInfo, success, failure) {
            var xhr, formData;

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.withCredentials = false;
            xhr.open('POST', 'queries/editorImageUpload.php');

            xhr.onload = function() {
              var json;

              if (xhr.status != 200) {
                failure('HTTP Error: ' + xhr.status);
                return;
              }

              console.log(xhr.response);
              //your validation with the responce goes here

              success(xhr.response);
            };

            formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());

            xhr.send(formData);
       }
```

I want to send another piece of data to the 'editorImageUpload' page being the name of the directory that it will add the image to. But I am unsure of how to add this. Would I just add it to the append line?:

```js
formData.append('file','directoryNameGoesHere', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
```

Or does that mess up the structure of the append. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add more values to send, just append them like you did with the Blob

```
        formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
        formData.append('directory','path/to/whereever');
```

Then read the `$_POST['directory']` for the value

Answer (score 0):

Note, that the last field must be the file itself. So, add any additional fields before the file.

```
    formData.append('directory','path/to/whereever');
    formData.append('file', blobInfo.blob(), blobInfo.filename());
```